# Attach a running console application to a new ConEmu instance

Tags: windows, console, conemu

I have an already-started console application, under Windows XP. I want to attach it to a different console emulator such as [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) or [ConEmu](https://sourceforge.net/projects/conemu/). This is [possible with ConEmu](https://superuser.com/questions/194211/replacing-the-default-console-emulator-under-windows-xp/444612#444612), and it works if I run ConEmu then use its "Attach to" menu entry and select my console application in the list.

I am now trying to automate this. I want to be able to focus the console application window, press a key, and have it attached to a new instance of ConEmu. I tried to write an [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) macro to attach the currently focused console application when I press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, but I can't figure out how to use `ConEmuC`. Here's my attempt:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass
#a::
  WinGet, app_pid, PID
  Run c:\opt\ConEmu-120704\ConEmu.exe /detached, , , conemu_pid
  Run c:\opt\ConEmu-120704\ConEmu\ConEmuC.exe /ATTACH /PID=%app_pid%
  Return
```

All I get the following error popup:

> ```
> Attach to GUI was requested, but there is no console processes!
>
> c:\opt\ConEmu-120704\ConEmu\ConEmuC.exe /ATTACH /PID=7104
> ```

Yet if I use the “Attach to” menu entry in the ConEmu instance, the console application gets attached. I need to tick the “alternative mode” checkbox [introduced in version 120704](https://superuser.com/questions/194211/replacing-the-default-console-emulator-under-windows-xp/444612#444612), if that's relevant.

How do I use `ConEmuC` (or any other method) to attach an existing console application to a new ConEmu instance? Even better, how do I attach an existing instance (if I want a new instance, I can just create it beforehand)? And how do I specify alternative mode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass
#a::
  WinGet, app_pid, PID
  Run c:\opt\ConEmu-120704\ConEmu\ConEmuC.exe /ATTACH /CONPID=%app_pid%
  Return
```

Alternative mode: `/ATTACH /CONPID=<pid>`.

Starting `ConEmu.exe /detached` is unnecessary. GUI will be started automatically, if not found.

**UPD**. Build 120705. If you want to unconditionally start new ConEmu window, you may add `/GHWND=NEW` to `ConEmuC` arguments.

**UPD 2**. On the other hand, may be you do not need to do `Attach` at all? There is [Default terminal](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/DefaultTerminal) feature which allows you to run ConEmu automatically "instead" of standard windows terminal when you run any console application.

Comment: Ah, `/CONPID`, ok. Is there a way to specify that I want a new ConEmu window and not a new tab in an existing window?

Comment: If you want new ConEmu window, run `ConEmu.exe /detached` and wait a little, while GUI window will be created. In the current version there is no special switch in `ConEmuC` for this case.