# Replacing cmd.exe with an another console tool

Tags: windows, path, console, redirection

I like to use [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/files/) instead of the default command line for Windows. Out of habbit i'm still writing "cmd" into Total Commander's command line sometimes to open a DOS console into the current directory. And it doesn't open Console2 of course and it makes me angry. :) I wonder if it's possible to redirect the "cmd" command to run Console2 instead of cmd.exe?

I've already tried adding Console2's folder to the PATH and creating a cmd.lnk file pointing to console2.exe but it's not working. I don't think it's a good idea to rename cmd.exe to something else and simply copy console2.exe as cmd.exe into SYSTEM32.

Comment: This has been asked before: http://superuser.com/questions/194211/replacing-the-default-console-emulator-under-windows-xp?rq=1

Comment: Not a dup, that question is asking how to replace the console windows of every program.  This is just how to replace `cmd`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You may want to use [`ConEmu`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/conemu/) for this.

To configure this, follow the steps.

1. Open Settings(press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>).

   [image]
2. In the next window, on the left side click `Default term`.

   [image]
3. Check the option `Force ConEmu as default terminal for console applications`.

   [image]

Comment: Wow! I haven't heard about ConEmu. Very cool that i can mix MS-DOS and Cygwin shells into the same window with this :)

Comment: You're missing an incredibly important step: 0. Run ConEmu. I thought `Win` +`Alt` +`p` was some Windows shortcut I'd never heard of.